# Assigning a Func to an Expression and vice versa

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, func

I was tampering with Expressions and I got confused at some points

1. We can assign same LamdaExpression to both Expression and/or Func. But we cannot assign a Func to an Expression (or an Expression to Func). Why cannot we do that? I looked for if a conversion operator between Expression and Func is defined but I could not found any.

   ```
   Func<int, int> sumFunc            = i => i + i;
   Expression<Func<int, int>> sumExp = i => i + i;

   // sumExp = sumFunc; // Cannot convert source type 'System.Func<int,int>' to target type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<int,int>>'
   // sumFunc = sumExp; // Cannot convert source type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<int,int>>' to target type 'System.Func<int,int>'
   ```
2. Even we cannot assign a LambdaExpression to an object. Again, why cannot we do that?

   ```
   // object o = i => i + i; // Cannot convert source type 'lambda expression' to target type 'object'
   ```
3. I think there is something about compiler. If so, can we write our custom types those behave in this (confusing) manner and take advantage of something.

Comment: You can call compile() on an expression tree to get a func. The other way is largely impossible: it requires an AST, which is very hard to construct for arbitrary IL

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Regarding to the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) a lambda expression like

```
i => i + i
```

is an anonymous function. An expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type. This is why you can write both

```
Func<int, int> sumFunc            = i => i + i;
Expression<Func<int, int>> sumExp = i => i + i;
```

The first is a delegate type, the second an expression tree type. Because there is no implicit converting between those types, you cannot assign `sumFunc = sumExp` or vice versa. But since the expression tree `sumExp` represents a lambda expression, you can compile that expression to an executable delegate and assign it to `sumFunc`, because this is such a compatible delegate:

```
sumFunc = sumExp.Compile();
```

The other direction is not possible, because a delegate cannot easily be "decompiled" into an expression tree.

The reason why you cannot write

```
object o = i => i + i;
```

is, that an anonymous function does not have a value or type in and of itself, it is just convertible to a delegate or expression tree type. You have to tell the compiler which of both you want, so you can convert it at first and then assign the result to a variable of type `object`:

```
object sumFuncObject = (Func<int, int>) (i => i + i);
object sumExpObject = (Expression<Func<int, int>>) (i => i + i);
```

Regarding your last question: You can create custom implicit or explicit conversions between complex types, so that this "magic" can be applied to assignments. See the [Conversion Operations Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Actually both of these expressions are syntax sugar, transformed by compiler in different language constructions.

When you write lambda expression, compiler does this: makes member function that matches your lamda expression and assigns it to your sumFunc variable (this is not exact code, just to get an idea):

```
class Program
{
   private static int generatedname(int i)
   {
        return i + i;
   }

   static void Main()
   {
       Func<int, int> sumFunc = generatedname;
   } 
}
```

When you write Expression tree there is even more magic happens. At compile time compiler transforms your expression into Expression tree "construction". Like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var addPrm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
        Expression<Func<int, int>> sumExp = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(
                Expression.Add(
                    addPrm,
                    addPrm
                ),
                addPrm
            );
    } 
}
```

You see this is completely different things, thats why you can not simply cast one to another.

Answer (score 0):

An expression is an abstraction. It permits Linq to efficiently build SQL queries for databases, for XML, or for another data source. It is similar in concept to an abstract syntax tree, it stores the syntactic elements of the query so the Linq provider can build a query.

If it worked as you are expecting, what it would have to do is take the abstract syntax tree of the lambda function and generate a tree of expression objects. Well, that's not really possible as far as I know, and what good would it be anyway?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?  Surely you can iterate through the abstract syntax tree and generate a recursive collection of objects.  Whether that's at all useful is another question.

Comment: Sure it would be possible. There is probably a much better way, but at worst you could reverse engineer the IL (programmatically) and generate an expression tree. But why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you make them a real method (instead of lambda), you can use a single "invoke" node in the expression tree to run the function. If you need arbitrary lambdas, I'm not sure off hand how to do that.